# Command line arguments not being passed in correctly

Tags: c, command-line

I am writing a function that works with BMP files. I am having issues with passing in command line arguments.

Whenever I used the debugger, it says that all my variables have been made equal to zero. Why is this? I would like it to be equal to the command line arguments.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int side_length = 200;
    int x_offset = 0;
    int y_offset = 0;
    double r = 1.0;
    double g = 1.0;
    double b = 1.0;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc - 1 ; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "-s"))
        {
            side_length = atoi(argv[i+1]);
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-x"))
        {
            x_offset = atoi(argv[i+1]);
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-y"))
        {
            y_offset = atoi(argv[i+1]);
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-r"))
        {
            r = atof(argv[i+1]);
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-g"))
        {
            g = atof(argv[i+1]);
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-b"))
        {
            b = atof(argv[i+1]);
        }
    }
    draw_waves(side_length, x_offset, y_offset, r, g, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp(argv[i], "-s")` --> `strcmp(argv[i], "-s")==0` or `!strcmp(argv[i], "-s")`

Comment: What debugger are you using?

Comment: 'Tis better to use the (POSIX or GNU) [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) function.  All else apart, after testing for one of the options, you convert the next argument, but you don't skip that.  So, if the user does `-b -4`, you might get funny results.  It doesn't hurt while you don't report unrecognized options; it would if you did. (There's an `else` missing in the loop.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Ah! Thank you!

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Fixed the problem, but I was using gdb

Comment: it is legitimate for a command line argument to be `-r20` but the code does not handle that.   When the code has a statement like: `b = atof(argv[i+1]);` The statement should be followed by: `i++;` so the next argument is not processed twice

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` returns 0 when the two strings are equal, so you should do something like this:

`if(strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with your current code. Here's something closer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int side_length = 200;
    int x_offset = 0;
    int y_offset = 0;
    double r = 1.0;
    double g = 1.0;
    double b = 1.0;
    for (int i_flag = 1; i_flag < argc; i_flag += 2) {
        int i_val = i_flag + 1;
        if (i_val >= argc) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Missing value for flag %s\n", argv[i_flag]);
            return 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(argv[i_flag], "-s") == 0) side_length = atoi(argv[i_val]);
        else if (strcmp(argv[i_flag], "-x") == 0) x_offset = atoi(argv[i_val]);
        else if(strcmp(argv[i_flag], "-y") == 0) y_offset = atoi(argv[i_val]);
        else if(strcmp(argv[i_flag], "-r") == 0) r = atof(argv[i_val]);
        else if(strcmp(argv[i_flag], "-g") == 0) g = atof(argv[i_val]);
        else if(strcmp(argv[i_flag], "-b") == 0) b = atof(argv[i_val]);
        else {
          fprintf(stderr, "Unknown flag %s\n", argv[i_flag]);
          return 2;
        }
    }
    printf("side=%d xofs=%d yofs=%d r=%f g=%f b=%f\n",
      side_length, x_offset, y_offset, r, g, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Then

```
$ gcc foo.c -o foo
$ ./foo
side=200 xofs=0 yofs=0 r=1.000000 g=1.000000 b=1.000000
$ ./foo -s 1 -x 2 -y 3 -r 1.5 -g 2.5 -b 3.5
side=1 xofs=2 yofs=3 r=1.500000 g=2.500000 b=3.500000
$ ./foo -a 1
Unknown flag -a
$ ./foo -a
Missing value for flag -a
```

A remaining weakness is that `atoi` and `atof` silently return zero for bad args. This isn't a good thing. Consider using `sscanf` and checking its return value to verify correct conversion.